# Get certain category name using woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to echo a certain category name to my product. 
Example: 
I have three categories with subcategories inside,

-Hairtype

-Gender

--Male

--Female

-Brand

--Loreal

-- etc

I need to echo out Brand subcategory(Loreal) name to my product.

Currently I have this piece of code that actually kind of works but it will echo out any name:

```
$terms =  get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    echo $terms[0]->name;
}
```

How can I narrow it down to echo only Brand subcategory ?
If i dont have Brand and Loreal selected then it echos out gender type.